# Generate file from same asp page for download instead of redirecting to a new page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file, html, response.redirect

I have a page PageA. Usually if I need to generate a file, I redirect to a new dummy PageB. There i write a bunch of Response.writes in its Pageload.From Page A I redirect to PageB and then I get a file to download.

Now can I instead of going/redirecting to a new page create the file in Page A itself? Basically copy the logic in PageB Pageload and create function here in PageA and use it?Can I do this? I have tried doing this but going no where. I have a situation where the above process is not working. I have a div and it is supposed to close, but doing a response.redirect is stopping the div from closing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484883/showing-and-closing-div-in-asp-net-with-some-changes). So looking for alternatives.

Comment: post some code that you tried if u really want some hepl...

Comment: write your code to download file in a webHandler(.ashx). Give the link to webHandler (proper parameters if required) in the PageA. The MIME type must be specified correctly to download the file in correct format.

Comment: @SubinJacob. I tried with ashx file. Still no go. I get the file to download but the pop up does not disappear. This is actually linked to my first question. Did you find the link in the above question? How does Response.Redirect affect my window close.?

Comment: @RookieAppler When you call the response.redirect method the code execution will be stopped and redirected to the page you specified.

Comment: there is no need of pageB just to download a file. You can do it in pageA itself. copy all your file download code from pageB to pageA